# libnih-dbus1:amd64 and libnih1:amd64 update errors after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: 22.04

recently moved from 20.04 to 22.04.

Here is what I am getting. I forced removal via dpkg and did a -f with apt but can't get past the error.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

```
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gcc-10-base gcc-10-base:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnih-dbus1 libnih1
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/63.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnih-dbus1_1.0.3-12build1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 package libnih-dbus1:amd64 (1.0.3-12build1) with field 'Multi-Arch: no' is not co-installable with libnih-dbus1 which has multiple installed instances
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnih1_1.0.3-12build1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 package libnih1:amd64 (1.0.3-12build1) with field 'Multi-Arch: no' is not co-installable with libnih1 which has multiple installed instances
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnih-dbus1_1.0.3-12build1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnih1_1.0.3-12build1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading. I solved this way:

```
sudo apt purge libnih1:i386 libnih-dbus1:i386 && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

I found the solution here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnih/+bug/1948346

Comment: That worked, I could not find the full lib names, that was my issue. Thank you very much!